# overload operator>> for a specific class

Tags: c++, qt

I implement operator overloading for both >> and <<

it seems there is no problem with <<

but for implementing operator>> like following , I got a runtime error

```
QDataStream & operator>> (QDataStream & stream, chromosome & myChromosome){

    myChromosome = chromosome();

    double len, wing1, wing2, tail, head;
    int index;

    stream >> head >> len >> tail >> wing1 >> wing2 >> index;

    myChromosome.setChromosomeHeadLength(head);
    myChromosome.setChromosomeLength(len);
    myChromosome.setChromosomeTailLength(tail);
    myChromosome.setChromosomeWing1Length(wing1);
    myChromosome.setChromosomeWing2Length(wing2);
    myChromosome.setIndex(index);

    return stream;
}
```

I debug this part, and program stoped (runtime error), when i get to `myChromosome.setChromosomeHeadLength(head);`

**EDIT:**
code for chromosome:

```
chromosome::chromosome()
{
    chromosomeLength = 0;
    chromosomeHeadLength = 0;
    chromosomeTailLength = 0;
    chromosomeWing1Length = 0;
    chromosomeWing2Length = 0;
    index = 0;

    topLeftX=0;
    topLeftY=0;
    bottomRightX=0;
    bottomRightY=0;
}
...
void chromosome::setChromosomeLength(double lenght){
    chromosomeLength = lenght;
}

void chromosome::setChromosomeHeadLength(double lenght){
    chromosomeHeadLength = lenght;
}

void chromosome::setChromosomeTailLength(double lenght){
    chromosomeTailLength = lenght;
}

void chromosome::setChromosomeWing1Length(double lenght){
    chromosomeWing1Length = lenght;
}

void chromosome::setChromosomeWing2Length(double lenght){
    chromosomeWing2Length = lenght;
}
```

when I run the program, error is:
*myProgram.exe has stoped working*

and when I debug it, I got this
[image]

EDIT 2:
more code, using operator>> and <<

```
void TabView::save(QDataStream &stream)
{

    stream << numberOfChromosomes;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfChromosomes; i++){
        stream << chromosomes[i];
    }
...
}

bool TabView::load(QDataStream &stream){    

    stream >> numberOfChromosomes;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfChromosomes; i++){
        stream >> chromosomes[i];
    }
...
}
```

any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Please post *the error message* in the question, **verbatim**.

Comment: I think you should post the code for `chromosome`. At this point it could be anything. You should know that just because a program crashes in one place does *not* mean that the error is in that place.

Comment: What do the assignment operators/copy constructors of `chromosome` do?  This like `myChromosome = chromosome()` is _at least_ unnecessary, if not a direct cause of your issues.

Comment: I concur with @john. This at-least-smells like a shallow-copy violation of the Rof3 if it pans out to have dynamic members that are not properly house-kept.

Comment: so I add chromosome code and error messages

Comment: @Chad there is no difference by removing that line you said.

Comment: Yes, remove the line and I bet you get the same error on the following line. Which means it's due to you dodgy assignment to my chromosome.

Comment: so what's your advice @dr.mo ?

Comment: OK nothing wrong with the posted code yet. You could post some more code, for instance how about the code where you call operator>>. But perhaps you should just learn how to use a debugger. The short answer is that there's nothing wrong with your operator>> code, you just have a bug somewhere else in your program. At the moment it's impossible to say where.

Comment: OK @john I've added what you want. BTW I know how to use debugger.

Comment: @dare Well given that latest code I would say the likeliest cause is that you've failed to manage the array/vector of chromosomes correctly. There's nothing that obviously makes the chromosomes array the right size. In other words it's a bug in the TabView class. Maybe you could check that theory out with the debugger.

Comment: Your error is in the first line of the function. Remove that line. Think very carefully about why you need to assign to an argument you've just passed in!! And then fix it

Comment: @dr.mo That line is not an error. The whole purpose of an operator>> is to assign to the second parameter.

Comment: @dr.mo as I said before , I've removed that line, and there is no diff

Comment: Ok, in which case have you tried to remove the line "myChromosome.setChromosomeHeadLength(head);" ?

Comment: @dr.mo , so if I remove that line, why I should overload operator>> ?

Comment: Just to test what happens! Because if the program still crashes when you remove that line it means the fault is somewhere else

Comment: Infact I suggest you progressively remove lines until the program stops crashing, then let us know which line causes the problem.

Comment: @john as you said the operator overloading is fine, and I just forgot to allocate dynamic memory in some where else. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QDataStream & operator>> (QDataStream & stream, chromosome & myChromosome){

myChromosome = chromosome();
```

... omitted

This section looks really wonky to me. Looks to me like  you're passing a reference to `myChromosome` and then constructing a new one directly on top of it. I'm not sure if this is where the segmentation fault is, but it looks like (as other members have noted) a violation of the **RULE OF THREE** if you're using dynamically allocated memory.

Since you didn't provide a header definition for class `myChromosome`, my only guess is that when you create a new class using the assignment operator, you're invalidating some memory space. Remember, this is conjecture because you didn't provide a `.h` implementation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line of code. Assigning to a reference is perfectly legal (even expected). And given the partial definition of chromosome that has been posted a violation of the rule of three seems very unlikely. It appears to be a class of doubles, so no rule of three error is possible.

Comment: @john, I didn't say that assigning to a reference was illegal, I said not respecting the Rule of Three and performing this operation was illegal. Since the OP didn't provide header stuff, that is my best educated guess.

Comment: OK point taken, nevertheless I don't think rule of three is the problem, at least not in that class. The TabView class looks a more likely source of the error.

Comment: @TylerJandreau, the was i call load function before memory allocation to chromosomes.